# A basis of the Banach space $L^p(\mathbb T^\omega)$ consisting of characters

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, topological-groups

> **Problem:** For $1<p<\infty$, $p\ne 2$, has the complex Banach space $L^p(\mathbb T^\omega)$ got a Schauder basis consisting of characters of the compact topological group $\mathbb T^\omega$?

(This problem of Aleksander Pełczyński was written on 9.08.2015 by Michał Wojciechowski on [page 15](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewpage.php?vol=0&page=15) of [Volume 0](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewbook.php?vol=0) of the [Lviv Scottish Book](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/)).

The prize for a solution: *A dinner in "Szkocka".*